# slow mysql query with Like / match against

Tags: mysql, sql-like, match-against

I need to search for the closest Dialcode bigger than the actual one. For example the closest from 33 will be 331 or 332 (if 331 doesn't exist)... So it has to be 33xxxx, 34 is not valid.

These 2 queries work but are too slow (250ms/row):

```
SELECT Dialcode
FROM table
WHERE (Dialcode LIKE '$var%' AND Dialcode > '$var' AND Price IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY Dialcode ASC LIMIT 1

SELECT Dialcode
FROM table
WHERE (MATCH(Dialcode) AGAINST ('$var*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND Dialcode > '$var'
      AND Price IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY Dialcode ASC LIMIT 1
```

My Dialcode is a PRIMARY KEY BIGINT(15).

Is I do this, it's really fast (>1ms/row) but it's not exactly what I need:

```
SELECT Dialcode
FROM table
WHERE (Dialcode >= '$var' AND Price IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY Dialcode ASC LIMIT 1
```

So I guess my problem is the LIKE / MATCH AGAINST.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

UPDATE solution:

Solution adapted from raina77ow suggestion:

```
SELECT Dialcode FROM table WHERE (( (Dialcode BETWEEN $var * 1 AND ’9’ )
   OR (Dialcode BETWEEN $var * 10 AND $var.’99’ )   
   OR (Dialcode BETWEEN $var * 100 AND $var.’999’ )
OR (Dialcode BETWEEN $var * 1000 AND $var.’9999’ )
…
) AND Price IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY Dialcode ASC LIMIT 1
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Hm `LIKE` needs to cast to string/char, that might take a while. You could test that theory on a copy of the table: cast the column to a char, and see how that performs.

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer casting the column to a char, then building another index upon it; then simple LIKE CONCAT(value + '%') will do wonders, I suppose, as it should hit the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the main problem here is that index is built upon the numeric values of Dialcode - not the string ones. So both queries do not use index at all.

You can try to build a numeric function, the problem is that this function will have Dialcode in the left part of evaluation - so the index again won't be used.

Perhaps this approach might be more useful.

```
SELECT Dialcode 
FROM table 
WHERE ( (Dialcode BETWEEN %value% * 10 AND (%value%*10 + 9) 
   OR (Dialcode BETWEEN %value% * 100 AND (%value%*100 + 99) 
   OR (Dialcode BETWEEN %value% * 1000 AND (%value%*1000 + 999)
   ...
) AND Price IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Dialcode LIMIT 1;
```

It's ugly as hell (I even wrote this wrong the first two times - alfasin should get the credit for correcting me), yes, but it should hit the index. The alternative is using UNION (and not OR), but I suppose both queries will be executed the same way (it's not verified, though).

Comment: you probably meant: **AND %value% * 10 +9** instead of **AND %value% * 11 - 1** etc. I like your solution (+1)

Comment: Thanks, your math fu is better than mine. )

Comment: yep! that was the way to go! I modified it a bit because in that case 34 will match, and it should start strictly with 33... (for example)

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex, something like:

```
SELECT Dialcode
FROM table
WHERE Dialcode REGEXP '^[$var]'
ORDER BY Dialcode ASC LIMIT 1
```

I can't test it right now, but I believe it should work.

Comment: And LIKE is not `using regex`?

Comment: @raina77ow you probably meant to ask if *regex* is not using *LIKE* which is a good question and I guess it depends on the implementation. when comparing numbers I hope that the answer is "no" but honestly I don't know. easy to test and find out the running time of the query though ;)

Comment: I tested and it was faster but not as much as the BEETWEEN option.